# How to make `Spinner onItemSelected()` to update `ListView` items from arrays in `strings.xml`?

Tags: android, xml, listview, spinner

Starting on Android dev here and I have a question regarding the update of a `ListView`. 
Following some tutorials I was able to make:

- `Spinner` with 4 items (Client A, Client B, Client C, Client D);
- `ListView` with `Checkbox` and a `TextView` saying the projects of each Client;

Each Client has is own Projects and the idea is to update the `ListView` to show each client projects when selecting them in the `Spinner`, e.g:

1. `Client A` -> Project 1, Project 2, Project 3, (...), Project 7;
2. `Client B` -> Project 8, Project 9, (...), Project 16.

For this I use a `Base Adapter` refering to a `single_row.xml` to set the layout for each view.

The information about the clients is set on an array called `clientes_array` in the `strings.xml` file. There I also have arrays for the `projectsA` and `projectsB`.

`strings.xml`:

`<string-array name="clientes_array">
        <item>Cliente A</item>
        <item>Cliente B</item>
        <item>Cliente C</item>
        <item>Cliente D</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="projectoA">
        <item>Projecto #1</item>
        <item>Projecto #2</item>
        <item>Projecto #3</item>
        <item>Projecto #4</item>
        <item>Projecto #5</item>
        <item>Projecto #6</item>
        <item>Projecto #7</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="projectoB">
        <item>Projecto #8</item>
        <item>Projecto #9</item>
        <item>Projecto #10</item>
        <item>Projecto #11</item>
        <item>Projecto #12</item>
        <item>Projecto #13</item>
        <item>Projecto #14</item>
        <item>Projecto #15</item>
        <item>Projecto #16</item>
    </string-array>`

This is my `Activity` code:

`public class AddProj_Activity extends Activity implements
        AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

```
Spinner spinner1;
Button botaoAdd;
ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addproj_layout);

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    botaoAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addProj);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    listView.setAdapter(new Adaptador(this));

    ArrayAdapter adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.clientes_array, R.layout.spinner_item);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter2);

    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

class SingleRow {
    String projecto;

    public SingleRow(String projecto) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.projecto = projecto;
    }

}

class Adaptador extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<SingleRow> listSR;
    Context context;

    public Adaptador(Context c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        context = c;
        listSR = new ArrayList<SingleRow>();

        Resources res = c.getResources();
        String[] projecto = res.getStringArray(R.array.projectoA);

        for (int i = 0; i < projecto.length; i++) {
            listSR.add(new SingleRow(projecto[i]));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listSR.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listSR.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {// call to each row
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // Inflater -> goes toxml, reads properties and creates the object with those properties!
        // new object everytime: layout inflater || same object everytime:
        // findViewById
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, viewGroup, false);// ref to RelativeLayout
        TextView tV = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        CheckBox cBx = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

        SingleRow temp = listSR.get(i);

        tV.setText(temp.projecto);

        return row;
    }

}
```

}`

How can I get a specific client to get the array of projects?

`Client A` getting all the `projectsA`, `Client B` getting all the `projectsB`, etc. ??

What should I do now?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your adapter adding this method:

```
public void swapData(int resId) {
   Resources res = c.getResources();
   String[] projecto = res.getStringArray(resId);
   listSR.clear();
   for (int i = 0; i < projecto.length; i++) {
      listSR.add(new SingleRow(projecto[i]));

   notifyDatasetChanged(); 
}
```

Then in your onItemSelectedListener:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
    long id) {
    Adaptor adapter = (Adaptor)listView.getAdapter();
    switch (position) {
       case 0: {
          adapter.swapData(R.array.projectoA);
          break;
       }
       /* and so on*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @LuS! Thanks for your reply :)
but i might be doing something wrong... in the `swapData` method I changed `c` to `context` because it said it "cannot be resolved". That eliminated the erros but the app didnt do anything. Still doesn't up date the `ListView`. 
I also added the second case to `case 1:{adapter.swapData(R.array.projectoB);    break;} `

Comment: FIXED!!! @LuS thank you so much. Was putting things on the wrong places -.-' still a rookie here.
Thank you once more!

Answer (score 1):

```
   @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            adapter2.clear();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                // fill adapter2 with client A
                break;

            case 1:
                // fill adapter 2 with clientB 
                break;
            }

        }
```

Each time you click an item in your list view, you check which position is clicked and reform your contents of your adapter

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer but I dont quite understand :/
I tried adding `adapter2.clear` and gave me a ` java.lang.unsupportedoperationexception`...what should I do?

Comment: Lus has the right answer right there. I don't personally support changing contents of an adapter within the adapter itself but it's a good answer.

Comment: thank you for your help! 
I would also like to understand what you meant...what was your approach to the problem?

Comment: Well a good practice is to control your arrays, array adapters from outside of the adapter. It is just a modular way of things, like if there is something wrong with your contents, you won't be needing to control your adapter class and check if it is working or not. I would move the method swapData to the activity itself.